# Google sheets track the value of a cell on a daily basis

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a log/historical sheet that tracks the the value of a live cell `C4` on a daily basis. I've attached an image of what I want the output to look like.
The sheet name is `PRThistory` and the cell which changes on a daily basis is `C4`. I've already tried running my own code however I haven't been successful.

```
function HistoryLog() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRThistory");

  var source = sheet.getRange("C4");

  var values = source.getValues();

  values[0][0] = new Date();

  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);

};
```

[image: example]

Comment: As I recall Google provides App Script which can be triggered on change or cron basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  var values = source.getValues();

  values[0][0] = new Date();

  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
```

by

```
sheet.appendRow([new Date(), source.getValue()]);
```

Explanation

The problem with your code is that `source.getValues()` returns something like `[[500]]`, then `values[0][0] = new Date()` replaces `500` by the a date-time value.

Comment: Thanks, I have now got a working script, I did a bit of reformatting and it  got it working.

Comment: @Paco If the answer solves your question, accept it ([read what this means and see how to do it here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/899642)). This makes it easy to see that the question has been solved by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to setup a trigger in the Google App Script environment. It can be done right from the same place where you are posting the code, but from another tab on the left hand side. Trigger will fire on a daily basis in a specified time, and will run your script of reading the cell. Then the same script will send the received result to your spreadsheet of choice. You can also read the current time and post it in a cell next to your daily value, so it will become a nicely looking log of things.

Comment: Yes this was my next step, after I got the script working. Thanks

Comment: Sounds great. You need to accept an answer that helped you the most.